# How to test validation errors throw exact error and message in laravel unit tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit, tdd

How to test specific validation errors in php unit thrown in validation error ?
with below code we could check session has errors, but not the exact error

```
$this->assertSessionHasErrors();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unit Test Laravel's FormRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36978147/unit-test-laravels-formrequest)

Comment: > I'm using phpunit 7.5 and Lumen 5.8 - when using a unit test for your `Request` or rules, you can do `$this->expectException$this->expectException('Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException');` and `$this->expectExceptionMessage = "The name field is required";` - see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647836/how-do-i-test-for-an-exact-exception-message-rather-than-a-substring-with-phpu

Comment: Note: the exception doesn't contain the validation message! it just says `The given data was invalid`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Got the answer

```
    $errors = session('errors');
    $this->assertSessionHasErrors();
    $this->assertEquals($errors->get('name')[0],"Your error message for validation");
```

$errors is MessageBag object which stored in laravel session when validation error thrown
using $errors->get('name') you could see all the validation errors as an array

Comment: For Laravel 6.x (and probably earlier versions), check `assertSessionHasErrors`: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/http-tests#assert-session-has-errors

Comment: you may need to start your session in the test's `setUp()`

Comment: $key    = config('session.keys.errors');  $errors = session( $key );

Answer (score 23):

`assertSessionHasErrors` can receive an array, [as documented](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/http-tests#available-assertions):

```
$this->assertSessionHasErrors([
    'field' => 'Field error message.'
]);
```

Comment: you don't really need to put your error into session to test the validator. You can take errors from `ValidationException` like so `$ex->errors()`

Comment: Only the keys are used here. This doesn't test the error message, only that the field has a message.

Comment: I think that might have been true at one point, but as of 6.x, you **can** pass values to test specific error messages, in addition to the fields/keys themselves. PR'd that within Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/http-tests#assert-session-has-errors

Answer (score 5):

You may use the combination of `assertStatus` and `assertJson`

```
...
->assertStatus(422)
->assertJson([
     'errors' => [
          'field' => [
               'Error message'  
          ]
      ]
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

First I use

```
$this->post()
```

instead of

```
$this->jsonPost()
```

Dont know why, for certain reason, the session would not come out.

Then I just use

```
$response->assertSessionHasErrors('field_name', 'Error Message!');
```

---

To find out what are the error message, you must dump it

```
$response->dumpSession();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use $response->assertSessionHasErrors('key')

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-tests#assert-session-has-errors

an example for required attribute will be

```
$response = $this->json('POST', '/api/courses', $this->data([
    'name' => '',
    'api_token' => $this->user->api_token
]));

$response->assertSessionHasErrors('name');
```

You can add an extra assertion, to make sure that no entry was added to the database, in this case "assert no course was added"

```
$this->assertCount(0, Course::all());
```

For multiple required attributes you may use a loop something like the following:

```
collect(['name', 'description', 'amount'])->each(function ($field) {
    $response = $this->json('POST', '/api/courses', $this->data([
        $field => '',
        'api_token' => $this->user->api_token
    ]));

    $response->assertSessionHasErrors($field);
    $this->assertCount(0, Course::all());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also a more elegant way in my opinion:

If you throw an exception via the class *GeneralException* you can check in a unit test if the session has a *flash_danger* from throwing a exception.

Lets do a practical example: We want to test that the admin cannot activate an already activated catalogue item.

**Test function**

```
public function an_admin_cannot_activate_an_activated_catalogue()
{
    $catalogue = factory(Catalogue::class)->states('active')->create();
    $response = $this->get("/admin/questionnaire/catalogue/{$catalogue->id}/activate");
    $response->assertSessionHas(['flash_danger' => __('The catalogue item is already activated.')]);
}
```

**Model/Repro function**

If it is activated we throw an Exception which then can be checked by the test function.

```
public function activate(Catalogue $catalogue) : Catalogue
{
    if ($catalogue->is_active) {
        throw new GeneralException(__('The catalogue item is already activated.'));
    }

    $catalogue->is_active = 1;
    $activated = $catalogue->save();

    if($activated) {
        return $catalogue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

actually you can easily throw errors from validation using `dd()` and `session('errors')`

since errors bag is stored in session you could add `dd(session('errors'))` in your unit tests to see which fields you are missing.

and finally you can write more proper test by adding `$response->assertSessionHasErrors('field_name');`

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel 7**;
In my case, I needed to ensure there was no error.

But below did ignore form-validation errors (at least mine).

```php
$response->assertSessionHasNoErrors();
```

Hence I created a custom assert function in base `TestCase` class, like:

```php
use PHPUnit\Framework\Constraint\RegularExpression;

// ...

public static function assertNoErrorReport(TestResponse $response)
{
    $error = static::getViewError($response);
    if ( ! empty($error)) {
        $this->fail('View contains error:' . PHP_EOL . $error);
    }
    $response->assertSessionHasNoErrors();
}

public function assertHasErrorRegExp(string $pattern, TestResponse $response, string $message = '')
{
    $error = static::getViewError($response);
    static::assertThat($error, new RegularExpression($pattern),
        empty($message) ? $error : $message);
}

public static function getViewError(TestResponse $response)
{
    $content = $response->getOriginalContent();
    if ( ! $content) {
        static::fail('View content missing.');
    }
    if ($content instanceof View) {
        $data = $content->gatherData();
        $error = $data['error'] ?? $data['errors'] ?? null;

        // Casts array to string.
        if (is_array($error)) {
            $error = '[' . join(', ', $error) . ']';
        }
        // Casts Error-bag to string.
        $error = '' . $error;
        if ($error === '[]') {
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        static::fail('Response is not a View.');
    }

    return $data;
}
```

However, my `assertHasErrorRegExp(...)` could be used for OP's case.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 8+, you can use `assertInvalid` to test for specific validation errors

```php
// Assert that these fields have validation errors
$response->assertInvalid(['name', 'email']);


// Assert that these fields give particular validation fail messages
$response->assertInvalid([
    'name' => 'The name field is required.',
    'email' => 'valid email address',
]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-tests#validation-assertions